# Thickness of gymnastics rings

Tags: crossfit, gymnastics, rings

I want to buy some wooden gymnastics rings for my home gym. I have found models with 2.8,2.9,3.0,3.1 and 3.2 cm diameter. Since I have small hands my first idea was to go with the 2.8 cm rings. However my Kettlebells have 3.3 cm diameter handles and it works well. Moreover thicker ring handles should have a better pressure distribution on your hands when doing dips.

Are there any disadvantages if I take the 3.2 cm ones even if I have smaller hands? Any other points to consider?

Comment: There's a buying guide [here](https://www.ringtraining.com/Articles/training/130-compare-gymnastics-rings.html) They recommend 3cm thick for 90% of adults. Also note that if you can use gloves which will effectively make it thicker

Comment: Archive of dead link above: https://web.archive.org/web/20161207175523/http://www.ringtraining.com/Articles/training/130-compare-gymnastics-rings.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Official gymnastic rings are 2,8 cm wide while most gyms ones are 3,0 cm wide. As gymnasts wear padding/gloves the ring they use feel fatter. Many crossfit like rings are 3,2 wide.

The main difference between various thicknesses is how easy you can achieve a "false" grip. Narrower rings make it easier.

So if you have small hands and you want to practise strict muscle ups, crosses or other advanced gymnastic movements I suggest to buy 2,8 - 3,0 cm rings. If you just want to do dips, rows, kipping muscle ups and other basic movements you could buy whatever you want.

Wooden rings are better (indoor of course) than metal or plastic ones  because they are more grippy.